# Facet counts aren't displaying correct numbers after filtering on a different facet

Tags: elasticsearch, tire

If you have two facets, let's say category and tag, initially the counts are correct, but they don't go down after filtering on one of the facets. The idea being that if there are no records within category X with tag Y, and we're filtering by category X, tag Y should have a facet count of 0.

Of course, other facet counts in the same term (other categories) facet counts don't go down because they would be an OR rather than an AND.

Comment: can you post a more explicit example? facet queries, docs, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you filtering your facets?  Like this?

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {.....},
  "filter": { "term": { "some_field": "some_value"}},
  "facets: {.....}
}
```

If so, then it's not surprising. The top level `filter` parameter is for filtering your search results AFTER having calculated facets.  In fact, in 1.0 it has been renamed to `post_filter` precisely because of this confusion.

You want to use a `filtered` query instead:

```
GET /_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {.....},
      "filter": { "term": { "some_field": "some_value"}}
    }
  },
  "facets: {.....}
}
```

Comment: This makes total sense, and I'm assuming this is the issue. But, if I implement it like this and select category X, would the facet counts for all other categories be reduced to 0? (for the sake of discussion, I'm assuming that things only have one category)

Comment: Yes - unless I'm misunderstanding you.  More detail may help?

Comment: I have two filters: one for tags, one for categories. The idea is that filters of the same type should be additive, and of different type should narrow the results. So, if I am filtering on a category, it still shows all of the available categories in the facets (which makes sense because it is additive), but reduces the tag counts based whether or not they are matched in the filtered categories. Does that make sense??

Comment: Details = code :)  Preferably with "i'm getting X (example) but I'm expecting Y". Much easier to understand